# Access Windows Task credentials in the PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-server

I need to automate running a PowerShell script using Windows Task Scheduler. My problem is that in my PS script I need to send my credentials to a web service. I don't want to write my credentials in the file as it's plain text and easily accessible by others.

Can I have my script access the credentials I used in setting up the task?

Answer (score 16):

No, you can't have the script access the credentials you used in setting up the task.

However, you can store your credentials in a `[PSCredential]` object, then save that out to a file using `Export-Clixml`. When the script runs, import the credential with `Import-Clixml`.

The XML file will store the password encrypted, and it will only be able to be decrypted by the same user on the same computer (so you must store it as the user the task will be running as).

### Example code for storing credential:

```powershell
Get-Credential | Export-Clixml -Path C:\scripts\task\${env:USERNAME}_cred.xml
```

### Example code for retrieving credential:

```powershell
$cred = Import-Clixml -Path C:\scripts\task\${env:USERNAME}_cred.xml
```

Because the cred needs to be decrypted by the same user, I like to use the current user in the file name to be sure you're retrieving the correct file. It also helps in case you want to have multiple users run the script (you won't need different versions of it).

If you're using PowerShell cmdlets like `Invoke-RestMethod` or `Invoke-WebRequest` then it will take a `-Credential` parameter and you can pass the credential object directly.

If instead you need to build custom auth headers or send the credentials directly, then you need to get them from the object:

```powershell
$user = $cred.Username
$pass = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

**Note that `$pass` is not encrypted at this point, if you leave it in the credential object it's encrypted in memory.**

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks, testing it out

Comment: This looks like it should work, but I just get null credentials when doing it this way.  The XML file is created, but when loaded, no go, even though running as the same user that created it.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch are you also decrypting it on the same machine it was encrypted on? That's a requirement too. Also this method won't work in PowerShell Core (version 6+) even on Windows.

Comment: @briantist Yep, same machine.  It's a full GUI install, not a Core.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch by Core I don't mean Windows Server Core. "Windows PowerShell" is what's included with Windows, it's based on the full .Net Framework and it's all versions up until 5.1. From Version 6 onwards, PowerShell is based on .Net Core, is open source, and cross platform, but there are some differences. If you're using `powershell.exe` it's Windows PowerShell, if it's `pwsh.exe` it's PowerShell Core. Anyway I'm not sure just from this description what the issue is but it might warrant a new question detailing the steps you're taking.